# Trigger keystroke to type outside the browser (like on notepad) from the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

I am not sure if it works like that. I am working on a website that uses camera feed to produce specific output. It works fine while typing inside the browser using simulated keystrokes, but I was wondering if I can make it to type it outside the browser window.

Comment: what have you done so far in terms of coding?? It's good if you share a code also

Comment: You cannot. It would be a huge security problem if you could. Any JS on any page on the internet would be able to do anything on your computer.